# Cocoon cinclude from another pipeline

Tags: include, loopback, apache-cocoon

I've got a Cocoon setup with a pipeline whose transformer contains something like this:

```
<cinclude:include src="https://my-app/get-some-data" />
```

Now, the URL included there is actually coming from Cocoon, and I have a TLS certificate that Java doesn't trust, so I get errors about PKI certification paths. I can "easily" solve that (and have been for some time, now) by specifying a truststore for the JVM process that contains my server's TLS certificate in it.

I'd like to stop doing that for at least two reasons:

1. When my server certificate needs an update, I have to update my trust store and bounce Cocoon
2. It could be more efficient (no loopback HTTP request, no TLS handshake, etc.)

Does cinclude understand Cocoon-relative paths?

I'm looking for something like this:

```
<cinclude:include src="cocoon://get-some-data" />
```

Does something like that exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do exactly this. The desired syntax is already in the question, with a slight modification. For example, let's say we have this `match` configured within a `sitemap`:

```
<map:match pattern="get-some-data">
   ...
</map:match>

<map:match pattern="primary-request">
  ...
  <map:transform type="cinclude" />
  ..
</map:match>
```

Using `<cinclude>` within the "primary-request" pipeline to include from the other pipeline simply requires this:

```
<cinclude:include src="cocoon:/get-some-data?parameters" />
```

This specific will only work for pipelines within the same sitemap. If you need to reference pipelines in other sitemaps, it requires a bit more setup -- but that's outside the scope of the question, here.